# /csp default directory in G-WAN

Tags: performance, url-rewriting, g-wan

i'm looking for the best way (fastest) so that my domain.com points directly at my /csp directory. 
What instruction in a main.c file, present in the headlers directory I guess, would you advise ?

Comment: What do you mean points directly? Are you talking about pretty URL (Without '?')

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have `http://domain.com/` execute a `script` rather than load a static page then use an URI rewrite:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   const long state = (long)argv[0];
   if(state == HDL_AFTER_READ)
   {
      xbuf_t *read_xbuf = (xbuf_t*)get_env(argv, READ_XBUF);
      xbuf_replfrto(read_xbuf, read_xbuf->ptr, read_xbuf->ptr + 16, "/index.html", "/?index_1.c");

      // Note: you may have to look for the ending double-CRLF to check
      //       if there are other pipelined requests to rewrite
   }
   return 255; // execute next connection step
}
```

The name `"/?index_1.c"` is designed to use the same length as `"/index.html"` to avoid a memmove() during the rewrite (having the same length allows for an in-place rewrite).

Comment: Your solution is working only in the case where the url entered is "domaine.com/index.html". If we just enter "domain.com", then the index_1 page won't be charged !
Wouldn't that be more interesting to use the xbuf_repl() function instead of xbuf_replfrto() ? (by using for example xbuf_repl(read_xbuf, "/", "/?") in order to avoir writing "?" each time)
Thanks for all ;)